# moving a file to a folder in http server using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file on my website. I like to move that file to a folder present in the same path where the as the text file. how to achieve this? I know FTP can do it, but is there any other way? or what is the best way?

Comment: So the source location and the destination location are on the same server?  If that's the case then you don't need FTP, you can just move the file via the file system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx  (The code would need to be running on the server, of course.)

Comment: yes source and destination is on the server but I have no idea how I am going to make something that runs the code on the server. I am a habitual programmer, a beginner and teaching myself. Its not my field actually, further help please..

Comment: You say it's a website, and the tag is "vb.net".  Is it an ASP.NET website (or web application)?  If not, that's where you'll want to start.  There are lots of tutorials to get you going: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: David, I am working on VB.NET and just need to move the file.. thats it.. and that too, from VB and the webserver is linux based